# Are Reissner-Nordström black holes repulsive?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, reissner-nordstrom-metric

I'm not sure if I understand how the charged black holes work. The Reissner-Nordström metric is defined as

$$ds^2=\left(1-\frac{2M}{r}+\frac{Q^2}{r^2}\right)dt^2-\left(1-\frac{2M}{r}+\frac{Q^2}{r^2}\right)^{-1}dr^2-r^2d\Omega^2$$

From this metric we can get the potential for photons (we could get a very similar expression for massive particles)

$$V(r)=\frac{1}{r^2}\left(1-\frac{2M}{r}+\frac{Q^2}{r^2}\right)$$

This however means that approaching $r=0$, the potential grows to infinity.

The only way I understand it is that no object can reach singularity at $r=0$, because all would be repelled. If that's true, what would happen if we were to shoot a photon directly at such a black hole?

Comment: What is your "potential for photons" and how did you calculate it? It looks to me like the effective potential but with the angular momentum omitted. If you do mean the effective potential then it should be $$ V^2(r)=\frac{L^2}{r^2}\left(1-\frac{2M}{r}+\frac{Q^2}{r^2}\right)$$ where $L$ is the angular momentum.

Comment: Yeah, I meant the effective potential, I just factored out the angular momentum, so I got $$\left(\frac{dr}{d\lambda}\right)^2=L^2\left(\frac{1}{b^2}-\frac{1}{r^2}\left(1-\frac{2M}{r}+\frac{Q^2}{r^2}\right)\right)=L^2\left(\frac{1}{b^2}-V(r)\right)$$

 where $b$ is the impact parameter. However the problem still persists, the potential grows to infinity at $r=0$

Comment: That's because you cannot approach r = 0 and keep L constant. You'd need the orbital velocity to go to infinity.

Comment: But isn't that what happens with Schwarzschild black holes?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I see what you mean. Good point, and I'd guess that's because of the inner horizon. Once you get through the inner horizon the $r$ coordinate becomes spacelike again.